# Glossy gift box designing in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, page-layout, illustrator-effects

I have to design a glossy gift box for a client in various sizes. Can I create just one design which the printing company can use for various sizes or should my designs be dimension-specific? Also, how do I create layout for the gift box with the top and sides? Can I download a template from somewhere? The box is supposed to be glossy. Should I give the glossy effect in Illustrator or just ask the printing company to print it on glossy, metallic paper for the effect? How do I create metallic effects in CMYK?

Thanks!

Comment: Contact the printer

Comment: The printer guy deals with the client. So I was wondering if I could find a way around without approaching my client to give me the printing company's contact. But I will do that if there is no other way out.

Comment: There is no shame in a designer communicating with the printer on what they need.  I would strongly suggest asking the client who they are going to use because in the end if there is something wrong the printer could likely blame you and with some clients today they will believe it..  Contacting the printer shows professionalism and will make your job easier unless you may like to work on a project multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Matt. As far as what I have seen, in India, the printing companies do not provide complete information to designers since they have their own in house design team and they coax their clients to get things designed from them. But I will give it a shot. I will contact the printing company tomorrow to try and get the much needed info.

Comment: Furthermore, it always helps to have a good relation with a printer.  By doing so they may recommend you if you're easy to deal with and can implement a good workflow/design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create just one design which the printing company can use for
>   various sizes or should my designs be dimension-specific?

That would depend on what the printer wants and if your "design" is just a single logo on a box or if you're designing a full custom color box like so:

[image]

*Design from vandelaydesign*

> Also, how do I create layout for the gift box with the top and sides?

The printer may have a template on this or spec to provide you on how to setup your document.

> Can I download a template from somewhere?

Again, I would advise contacting the printer but there are some out there that provide templates and I've seen some go to other printing services and use their templates as a starting point.

> The box is supposed to be glossy. Should I give the glossy effect in
>   Illustrator or just ask the printing company to print it on glossy,
>   metallic paper for the effect?

The printer may be able to provide a sample for you.

> How do I create metallic effects in CMYK?

Typically its just a color that is called out as a metallic.  In the rip or platemaking process you will have to make sure the metallic layer is defined.

A little self promotion on the printer topic and it may be helpful:  [What should you ask the printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)

Comment: Thanks. The 'What should you ask the printer?' section was really helpful. I will contact them and I hope to get a favorable response which will ease things out greatly.

Comment: If it was helpful or if you find any answer or question helpful please make sure to use the voting system because we only get paid by votes and not money ;)

Comment: I cannot upvote since my reputation is below 15. I have accepted this answer. I hope that does not mean that the question will be closed. Because if I do not get any answers from the printing company, I might have to trouble y'all again!

Comment: We dont and we typically only close questions that are duplicates or of little effort which result in an unclear question..  and welcome to GD!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much :) I will keep you updated regarding what the printer says.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt. I spoke to the printer and he gave me the dimensions and solved all my other queries.