# What are the frequently used post-press processes in modern digital printing, to name a few?

Tags: print-design

I'm looking for alternatives to traditional printing processes to strengthen the physical aspects of digitally printed items. it seems with certain systems such as NEXPRESS Press Platform it's possible to add varnishes similar to those in traditional printing. I'm wondering what are the processes most frequently resorted to with such systems? — I realise this is a broad question, but as someone who's new to printing processes with digital presses, I do wish to learn a few facts about this area to have an overall impression.

Comment: Once again, a great question to ask a couple printers! :)

Comment: You realize this is incredibly broad? I mean you're basically asking us to list all of the systems and possibilities that exist for printing. Voting to close as a result. If you have a more specific question though on the topic then edit your question.

Comment: [What should you ask the printer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)

Comment: Ring round a few different printers, see what machines they have, get a rep to come out with loads of samples... have a coffee - tell them what you would like to achieve, they tell you what they can do - chat about pre-press and finishing services. LIFE STARTS NOW