# How to design a basic banner with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, print-design

I am using GIMP. And I want to design a very basic banner to be printed 3m long. The design is as simple as it could be : it consists of one logo that I have in pdf format (was designed by a professional graphic designer), and a bit of text.
I believe this is a very easy task that would take 10 min to complete for someone who knows.
It should be in 300dpi res. 
If I open a new file with 3m long dimensions and a 300 dpi res. the file will be a few GB big, and GIMP refuses to work with such a big file. (may not be the right way of doing)
Do you know how to get started with that ?

Thanks in advance for the valuable tips !

Comment: You'll be better off using a vector application, such as [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) or [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/en/products/illustrator.html). Assuming that you only use vector elements, you should be able to get away with .pdf file for the banner that is less that 1mb.

Comment: A vector app should be the choice for this - try inkscape. Regardless of that, if you ever need a raster image for a 3m wide banner you should really consider if you will need 300dpi resolution. That resolution is good enough for photographic at text-reading distance, such as magazine pages, or printed photos. A larger work can - and should - go by with a smaller resolution. 30 DPI should be enough for a banner this large.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but Paint.NET is better than GIMP on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Joonas I would use InkScape.  If you are set on using Gimp you may consider a different ratio instead of 1:1.  I would consult the printer with their desired specs and we do have some questions similar to this topic you may find helpful:

- [Should I design business cards in InDesign, Illustrator or Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/should-i-design-business-cards-in-indesign-illustrator-or-photoshop)
- [What should you ask the printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)
- [What DPI should be used for what situations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-dpi-should-be-used-for-what-situations)
- [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)
- [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

If you click on [print-design](/questions/tagged/print-design) you will generate all questions and answers related to print design.

Comment: In linking an answer of mine http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45833/how-to-create-a-very-big-photo-like-for-a-billboard/45844#45844 It can trow some light on the subject.