# How to create a very big photo (like for a billboard)

Tags: print-design, photo-editing, photography, pixelation

So I'm designing a CD cover for my friends band. And I will have to use a photo of them for that cover. How am I supposed to create it so that it won't pixelize if they want to use that for a big advertisement (like a billboard or something simmilar).
Sorry for my english, it's not my native lanugage :)

Comment: This question appears to be about photography, so it is off-topic here. (The only other SE site that shows up under "This question belongs on another site is gd's meta. Not very useful.)

Comment: @AlanGilbertson: Only frequently needed migration paths are selectable by regular users. The default way to migrate something is to flag it for moderator attention. Anyway, we need to make sure, it’s really welcome on Photography SE.

Answer (score 4):

The viewing distance of an image is somehow proportional to the size of the print.

For example you normally do not see a magazine from across the street, and you do not see a billboard very close.

That means that you can use the same photo on a magazine and on a billboard.

If you have a 10Mpx photo, guess what? You use your 10Mpx photo.

[image: Viewing distance vs ppi] 
(These imagee have a mistake: Where they say *dpi* it should read *ppi*.)

You need to do some things on a vector graphics program, like texts, logos and other stuff.

You can prepare your artboard on a scale. If you need a 4x3m billboard, you can do it at 40x30cm, and at the end export a jpg file.

Here is a graph to give you an idea, based on the previous explanation:

[image: Distance vs ppi graph]

Work on your image with Photoshop or Photowhatever, but insert the texts on a vector based program. Illustrator, Corel, InDesign, etc.