# what size should i use to print a shoppin bag?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, print-design, image-format

I need to design a shopping bag.

1. What sizes should I use for printing? It's a vertical bag. I know the sizes may vary according to shape.
2. What font sizes that should be used?
3. What file format should save the files in for print?

I am working in Adobe Photoshop.

[image]

here is the bag i want to be printed.
the current size is 32 x 22 inches.
the resolution is 72. I feel like i should increase resolution to 300?

Comment: How big is the _bag_?

Comment: The answer to questions 1. and 3. would be: 'ask your printer'.

Comment: We can't answer this, you're not telling us the print process, what kind of bag it is, the printer, etc. We can't know what font to use or the size of the bag; this depends greatly on the print process, some thin fonts won't print well for plastic bag since you need a minimum weigth to the strokes/paths (vectors). This question is incomplete!

Comment: Do not use Photoshop for this.

Comment: What resolution are you talking about... the resolution of your layout? Yes 300ppi is a standard and using vector is even better. Photoshop CAN be used for this but you need to make sure your black and white design (if solid) is in lineart (bitmap mode) at 600ppi and more ideally. You seem to have done your layout already, could you clarify why you ask for layout dimensions and font size? Do you need a critique of your work? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/critique/info  &  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer/21499#21499

Comment: I designed a flyer last time and sent it for printing. I made it using 300ppi with A5 Page size. The printing guy said that it's facing pixel breakage while doing offset printing. Although it was working fine with digital printing. That's why i am a little worried about printing this bag.

Comment: If you plan to be a graphic designer and design print projects, you really need to inform yourself about the different file types, vectors, raster, & different printing; for yourself & by respect to your clients. Yes digital hides the low quality of designs, it's almost like a cheap injket. Offset is serious business and requires perfect files. I already pointed out to convert to bitmap/lineart @ 600ppi or to redo your work in vector. Or print as is and maybe be responsible for a very badly printed batch of bag$! So go forth and search about these clues on this stack or post a new question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It really depends on your specs. The last one I did <strike>IIRC</strike> if I Recall Correctly was about 20" x 10" in 300 DPI. Unless its a totally custom bag, your printer probably has standard / default sizes (much like biz cards etc).
2. It really depends on a ton of factors, mainly the size of your canvas, DPI, etc. Personally I would ask your printer for a PSD template or at the very least the specs and go from there.
3. Once you have your canvas / work area defined, just use whatever font fits within your template. I'd start at 60 and work my way up.
4. Again this is going to depend on what your printer wants. Mine usually asks for a PDF but others want EPS or TIFF.

I did a shopping bag last year but just slapped a custom sticker on each bag, there are so many many options when it comes to printing a bag.

Comment: Depends what print process is also use and if the bad is in plastic or paper. For plastic then a vector is better.

Comment: Thanks alot patrick for a detailed answer. I am attaching and image.