# My print has lost color accuracy when rendered from Photoshop to a vinyl banner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb

Recently ordered a 10x3ft 15oz laminated vinyl banner for every-day outdoor  use.

This is what the banner looks like:

[image]

The colors used are:

White #ffffff

Blue #0071bc

Grey #8c8b8b

Black #000000

Even though the blue looks vivid and bright in the PSD design, when translated onto a vinyl banner, the blue looks very dim and loses all the brightness. Similar results happen with the grey, which I was hoping would look more like silver (the colors black and white are rendered perfectly).

I'm getting ready to re-order the same banner, but this time I want to make sure that the blue and the grey come out just as bright as they do on a computer screen / photoshop design.

I researched and found that **cyan** might be the best blue hue to achieve a bright blue color similar to the one shown on the image above. But at the same time, when I use cyan on this banner design in photoshop, the color looks like such a different blue. (My company corporate colors revolve around the blue shown in the image).

I have another design of this banner, which I also wanted to get printed to have some variation. I am cautious of ordering it now in case I have the same problem with the color not looking as bright as it looks on the PSD design. This banner is the same as the one shown above, but using a **red color hue #f5002e.**

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions and knowledge on the right colors (blue, red, grey) to use to achieve a bright and vivid result when rendering my design to a vinyl banner, so that the text can be easily seen from afar in outdoor, every-day usage.

Comment: The colors you mention are hexadecimal values - which are RGB colors. Your banner will be printed in CMYK. Converting colors from RGB to CMYK will almost always give you a duller color. You should (if you aren't already) be working in CMYK and (as has been said) talk to your printer.

Comment: FYI: the technical term for the color range of a color system is *gamut*. At the least, use the "squint test" to get a better idea of tonal contrast..

Comment: sidenote: do something drastic with that comma...

Comment: A simple text-based banner like this could be done with cut vinyl, which means your grey text could actually be silver vinyl.

Answer (score 4):

This is is where communication with the printer is key.  We cannot ideally help you without fully knowing what the requirements are.

- I wouldn't be using Photoshop I would be using a vector program such as InkScape or Illustrator
- You should ask the printer if they provide samples.
- Reference a pantone color guide and do not rely on what color Photoshop is showing on screen.
- Ask your printer if they have a template you are to use.
- Make sure your system is calibrated.

There are several questions you can ask, you could read this: [What should you ask the printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/what-should-you-ask-the-printer)

Comment: Also, they might even have Blue ink, or something. These are pretty basic colours, and the printer can guide you to create the best result.